# Symfony doctrine force to always query the database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an application in Symfony with mongodb where I have an application always running as a server. When I try to retrieve objects from the database I don't receive the newset values of the object. Is like doctrine is caching the objects and although there are other processes that updates the database, my application doesn't see the changes and always the first object retrieved is returned.

As a test I've programmed two processes, one writes values and the other one reads those values, as you can see the reader always sees the same value.

[image: getter always sees a zero value]

This is the code of the two processes:

```
class SetterCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand 
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('delfos:setter')
            ->setDescription('Sets value');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){

        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
        $element = $em->getRepository('DelfosBundle:TestDoc')->findOneById("46e05892b50334e0badbb8cac9a076a7");
        $i = 0;

        while(true){
            $element->setIndex($i);
            $em->persist($element);
            $em->flush();
            echo "Setting value to ".$i.PHP_EOL;
            $i++;
            sleep(2);
        }
    }
}


class GetterCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand 
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('delfos:getter')
            ->setDescription('Gets value');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();

        while(true){
            $element = $em->getRepository('DelfosBundle:TestDoc')->findOneById("46e05892b50334e0badbb8cac9a076a7");
            echo "Current value ".$element->getIndex().PHP_EOL;
            sleep(2);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class TestDoc
{

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Int
     */
    protected $index;

    ...
}
```

How can I force doctrine in this process to always query the database?

Comment: Try to detach the previously queried object before re-executing the query
`$entityManager->detach($object);`

Comment: This does not make sense - you get element like this (always same query) `$element = $em->getRepository('DelfosBundle:TestDoc')->findOneById("46e05892b50334e0badbb8cac9a076a7");`  and expect different result?

Comment: $entityManager->detach($object) woks correctly, but there isn't any way to do it automatically?

Comment: @pavlovich Of course I expect different results, as there ar two concurrent processes, one changing the value and another reading the value from the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use QueryBuilder and set refresh hint to `true` on the query you build with [setRefresh()](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Query/Query.php#L184) method.

Comment: This is the way to go. Doctrine has an identity map where it stores every objects requested, and will eventually use it as a cache.

Comment: Ok, this works too, but there isn't a way to force to always fetch the database instead of doing it in every query I have? something like $em->setRefresh(false); and from that point force to avoid any query being cached?

Comment: Not that i know of. PHP is web dev language designed to handle request-response use cases not for long running tasks. You can do long running task with PHP but you are probably better of doing it in some other language. You could try `$entityManager->clear()` at the beginning of your loop.